# How to delete plist keys using AppleScript

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, macos, applescript

I have plist file as shown below:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string></string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>en</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I want to delete Dictionary tags within the `CFBundleURLName` tag. And I want to delete all `string` tags within the `CFBundleLocalizations` tag.

How can I do this using AppleScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just gone through the same situation and found these two apple thread discussion. As per discussion there is no command by which you can delete plist key objects directly.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/12578430#12578430

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/771027?tstart=0

You may achieve this by using shell script.

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to remove keys from your plist:

```
set aScript to "defaults delete /path/to/your/com.dsah.plist keyname"
do shell script aScript with administrator privileges
```

You'll have to write your plist to a file first. To delete all CFBundleLocalizations strings, you should probably delete the CFBundleLocalizations key and then add an empty one.